# recognize classes in sub folder in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

In PyCharm, I have a class like this:

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self):
        self.speed = 0

    def say_state(self):
        print("I'm going {} kph!".format(self.speed))

    def increase_speed(self, increase):
        self.speed += increase
```

situated in a sub folder called Classes.

I have driver python file, which simply contains:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_car = Car()
    my_car.say_state()
    my_car.increase_speed(2)
    my_car.say_state()
```

Unfortunately the class Car is not recognized.

What do I have to do for the class Car to be recognized in the driver file?

I guess this is a simple one. Apologies my background is strongly type languages - C#.

PS:

Even if I put my class Car in the same folder as the Driver it is not automatically recognized. I have to include:

```
from Car import Car
```

So if I have a class that uses 10 classes, which is not unlikely in complex applications, do I really have to include 10 import statements? I would expect that a good IDE recognizes classes ion the same project without having to import them explicitly. Am I missing something or is this just like this with Python as it is interpreted?

Comment: TBH I never stored classes inside of different folders before. I am interested in knowing how you would go about this without importing the file as a module.

Comment: @Rob the driver does not even seem to recognize the class if the file is in the same folder.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious answer is to use import and import your own module.

As it is in a subfolder you should use the indirect import where `.` is your main module dirfoo1 is your directory foo1 is your submodule name.

```
from .dirfoo1.foo1 import Foo1
```

so in your case

```
from .Classes.Car import Car
```

Comment: Mmh so if I follow the SOLID principle in python, as I do in C#, I potentially have tons of import statements like this?

Comment: Yes, i'm not sure and am unable to check now but if you import x to file y and import y to file z i think you can use something from x in z

Answer (score 0):

If you have two python scripts located in the same directory ie:

```
# first_script.py

def foo(): print("stuff")
```

then you simply import the first script into the one your working on:

```
# second_script.py
import first_script
first_script.foo()    # prints "stuff"
```

That should be working. It gets a bit more complicated when these scripts are located in different directories. If they are located in different directories you are going to need a `__init__.py` in the directory you are pulling from; that much I am sure of. However, beyond that I am not so sure.

This compounds btw. So, if you have scripts a, b, c...n and a pulls from b which pulls from c which pulls from... n then a also pulls from n.

Comment: thanks. I am after 'proper' oop though not just 'procedural' programming with tons of functions in a bunch of scripts. I am used to be able to create class libraries for a particular concern and then reference these and use for example in a driver.

Comment: @cs0815 Np, if this answer is acceptable please click the accepted (green check-mark) next to the answer, gl!

Comment: Thanks I will accept it if there is no simpler way to do it.Besides your code is procedural and not a class definition.